# Array correlation issues

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to create an application that prompts a user for 5 names, then display each name and allow the user to enter a score for that particular name.  So if in the first array, the value for index [0] is a string "Bob", then in the other array for scores index [0] should be the score for bob.

I am having a hard time understand how to pass the nameArray[] to the PopulateScore() method so that it can display the name for the user to enter a corresponding score.

I also have to search the Array by name and return the score.

Thanks for any help.

```
public class InitArraya
{
    public static string[] arrayName = new string[5];
    public static int[] arrayScore = new int[5];

    public static void PopulateNameArray()
    {
        // Prompt user for names and assign values to the elements of the array
        for (int intCounter = 1; intCounter < arrayName.Length; intCounter++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter name {0}: ", intCounter);
            arrayName[intCounter] = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static void PopulateScoreArray(string[] array)
    {    
        // Prompt user for names and assign values to the elements of the array
        for (int intCounter = 1; intCounter < 5; intCounter++)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter score for {0}: ", arrayName[0]);
            arrayScore[intCounter] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    public static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 names:"); // headings

        PopulateNameArray();
        PopulateScoreArray(arrayName);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting some kind of error message?

Comment: @Jonathan So what is the problem here?

Comment: I think you use an incorrect data-structure here. You want to map a name with a value, so you should you `Dictionary<key,value>`.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: There are no problems with your syntax but I think that you need to change `arrayName[0]` to `arrayName[intCounter]`. Please also remember that arrays are Zero-Indexed. Have a great day :)

Comment: I need to search the nameArray and return the corresponding index value from scoreArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in

```
public static void PopulateScoreArray(string[] array)
```

change

```
 Console.Write("Enter score for {0}: ", arrayName[0]);
```

to

```
Console.Write("Enter score for {0}: ", array[intCounter]);
```

To use input array. Also in all for(-) change the start for counter to 0

```
for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < 5; intCounter++)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I now have to figure out how to search the array by name and then return the score, trying that now.

Answer (score 1):

Make array of objects which contains the name and score, this will make your solution much more usefull and readable.

```
public class NameScore{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Score { get; set; }
}

public class InitArraya{
    public NameScore[] arrayScore = new NameScore[5]; 
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void PopulateScoreArray(string[] array)
{

    // Prompt user for names and assign values to the elements of the array
    for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < array.Length; intCounter++)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter score for {0}: ", array[intCounter]);
        arrayScore[intCounter] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    }
}
```

Assuming that there are always 5 names in arrayName. Extra checks should be made otherwise.

Oh, and start intCounter at 0 in PopulateNameArray too.